# Wordpress prevent redirect when empty submit from custom login form

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication

I have a custom login form on page X and I have added the form with `wp_login_form( $args )`.

Then I have a login button `wp_loginout();` that takes me to *wp-login.php*.

I need the login button to take me to the *wp-login.php* page and I need that when submitting the custom login form with wrong or empty data, I need a redirect to the same page X.

At the moment I have implemented this bit of code

```
if( ! function_exists( 'custom_login_fail' ) ) {
function custom_login_fail( $username ) {
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // where did the post submission come from?
    // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
    if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
        if ( !strstr($referrer,'?login=failed') ) { // make sure we don’t append twice
            wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' ); // append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
        } else {
            wp_redirect( $referrer );
        }
        exit;
    }
}
}

add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'custom_login_fail' ); // hook failed login
if( ! function_exists( 'custom_login_empty' ) ) {
    function custom_login_empty(){
        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        if ( strstr($referrer,get_home_url()) && $user==null ) { // mylogin is the name of the loginpage.
            if ( !strstr($referrer,'?login=empty') ) { // prevent appending twice
                wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=empty' );
            } else {
                wp_redirect( $referrer );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'authenticate', 'custom_login_empty');
```

The redirect on page X when the submission is wrong or empty works as expected, but when I click on the login button on page X it doesn't take me to the *wp-login.php* page anymore but instead it takes me to pageX/?login=empty.

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Your browser is already redirected to `wp-login.php` during authorization request from login form on your page X.

I am not sure, but you better use asynchronious requests (which is hard to implement in WP) or copy user login code to your own code (using site plugin), so it will always authorize user on request on any page you will need.